# How to convert a .py file into a .exe file for Python 3.6.4

Tags: python-3.x

I need to convert my .py files into .exe files for Python 3.6.4.  I have tried almost everything on Google and YouTube and none of it seems to work for me.  It seems as though a lot of the explanations either gloss over the most technical aspects of installing any modules that convert .py files into .exe files or they are outdated.  Can someone give me a step by step example of how to convert my .py files into .exe files for Python 3.6.4.?  I was able to convert the .py files easily for Python 3.4 but not 3.6.4.  My file path is: This Pc > C: > Users > XXXX > AppData > Local > Programs > Python > Python36-32

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a Python script standalone executable to run without ANY dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the external packages are still not supporting 3.6.
Try with cx_Freeze in 3.6 else go with pyinstaller but python version should be 3.5(this works fine for me)